# Alembic log files

Tags: postgresql, alembic

I'm trying to run a basic alembic script that creates a table on localhost

```
revision = '43a24caf4e92'
down_revision = 'b61a0e474ffd'

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        'crawl',
        sa.Column('timestamp', sa.DateTime, default=sa.datetime.now, primary_key=True),
        sa.Column('raw_text', sa.String(50)),
        sa.Column('URL', sa.String(200))
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('crawl')
```

alembic-develop.hacked.ini has this:

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost/db_test
```

It runs successfully

```
$ alembic -c alembic-develop.hacked.ini upgrade 43a24caf4e92
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

However I looked at localhost using pgadmin4. I can't find the table. I know it ran, because if I put in a typo, alembic throws up an error. I can see the db on pgadmin4 but no table.

How would I debug this? Are logging options available for alembic?

Comment: I have a very similar problem with alembic but if I put in a typo it doesn't complain.